# Tetris - Smooth piece drop (c++)

Tags: c++, tetris

So I have coded simple tetris games on the past but I have never done one where the pieces drop smoothly, like for instance Super Tetris 3 on the SNES.I am planning to learn SDL and for such I want to code a Tetris on it.

My questions are two, as follow :

- Can you give me some hints as to how to code this?
- How hard is to code this compared to make the pieces fall in the easy way?

Comment: There is more than one way to "code a tetris game" and there is more than one "easy way" to make pieces fall. When you tell us more about your implementation details we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of many ways to do it.

First I will explain an algorithm for dropping the pieces, then I will explain how to drop them at intervals that don't line up with the grid...

--

0 background

1 piece 1

2 piece 2

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0
```

Form a matrix that defines each piece by the grid of square locations taken up by that piece.

Start by assuming all pieces are falling.

In each iteration, loop through every piece to determine which pieces are definitively anchored, and stop iterating when the previous iteration finds no new anchored pieces.

To determine whether a piece is anchored, loop through every component of the piece. If any of the following conditions are true, then the piece can be considered anchored.

1. A component is in the bottom row.
2. The space below a component is from another component that is determined to be anchored.

Once you have determined which pieces are falling you can update the matrix and the scene by dropping all the components of those pieces by 1 and restart the algorithm  until you have a situation where all pieces are anchored.

--

Now all you need to do is change the step size from 1 to 1/x. Pieces that are inbetween the grid of squares above do not need to be tested in the algorithm. If a piece is inbetween gridlines, then it is guaranteed to be falling, and you can continue dropping it until it lines up with the grid.

Make sure that it lines up with the grid every x steps (if using floating point numbers, some rounding/grid snapping will be required.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this issue in my grid based puzzler:

When a piece goes down you already have them fixed to the next designated position in the array, but you offset your Y coordinates by one grid cell high and simply update that offset by fall speed. When that offset reaches zero you move the pieces to the next grid position below and offset the Y again to make it animate again.

Or slightly different:

When a piece goes down you already have them fixed to a designated position at the *bottom* on the board and simply animate the offset downwards. You'd have to recalculate the offset once you move or rotate your pieces.

It might be handy to give your pieces some state to know if it's still falling or if it's already static.

Keep in mind that this could be very rigid to your liking but personally it worked out pretty well for me.